# Status bar while downloading

Tags: java

I have a simple java project, which has the option to download a .zip file from Internet. The download takes around 1-2 minutes - 100MB. Is there any whay to show in outpute the progess of the downloading - for example percent completed, or how many MB left to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up an asynchronous reader to a JProgressBar (or some other custom component) as I did here: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ProgressBarForDataFetching.java

You are welcome to use this code if it fits your requirements